# avoiding chunked encoding of HTTP/1.1 response

Tags: http, http-headers, chunked-encoding

I want to avoid ever getting *chunked* encoded HTTP server response from (conforming) HTTP server. I am reading [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) section "[14.39 TE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.39)" and it seems to me that I could avoid it by specifying `TE: chunked;q=0`. If I cannot avoid the *chunked* encoding, I want do avoid the trailers. Will specifying `TE: trailers;q=0` work?

Comment: The title was:
"avoiding chunked encoding of HTTP/1.1 response"
but you wrote:
"I want to avoid ever getting chunked encoded HTTP server response from (conforming) HTTP server" So if you are allowed to send a HTTP 1.0 GET request instead of 1.1, transfers will not be chunked (no chunk size dirtying your buffers)

Comment: I do not remember the exact situation any more. I vaguely remember I needed HTTP/1.1 for some reason in the request and I wanted to avoid the chunked encoding because it was hard to distinguish trailing headers of the chunked encoding from headers of new requests in the libcurl callbacks I was using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [rfc2616 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) in section [3.6.1 Chunked Transfer Coding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1):

> All HTTP/1.1 applications MUST be able to receive and decode the
> "chunked" transfer-coding, and MUST ignore chunk-extension extensions
> they do not understand.

This is still the case in the updated [RFC 7230 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) in section [4.1. Chunked Transfer Coding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1) although in a slightly different wording:

> A recipient MUST be able to parse and decode the chunked transfer
> coding.

So if you want to be conform to HTTP/1.1, you will have to accept chunked encoding.

---

##Update##

As for the trailers: I think if you don't send a `TE` header field in your request, a conforming server shouldn't send you any trailers. If it still sends trailers you are probably save to ignore them (again section 3.6.1):

> A server using chunked transfer-coding in a response MUST NOT use the
> trailer for any header fields unless at least one of the following is
> true:

> a) the request included a TE header field that indicates "trailers" is
> acceptable in the transfer-coding of the  response, as described in
> section 14.39; or,

> b) the server is the origin server for the response, the trailer
> fields consist entirely of optional metadata, and the recipient
> could use the message (in a manner acceptable to the origin server)
> without receiving this metadata.  In other words, the origin server
> is willing to accept the possibility that the trailer fields might
> be silently discarded along the path to the client.

Comment: Thanks. I hoped I was not reading the RFC right and that the `q=0` could override this. :)

Comment: @wilx You're welcome. As for the trailers: just don't send a `TE` header field or ignore the trailers. (See my update...)

Comment: Unfortunately if you have to write code to ignore trailers it is almost as easy as to handle them. And i whish there were a http test case server because i still have to look for some server which sends trailers or more exotic any chunk parameters.