# I can't get the response for my POST request, if I try to get anything from the response it will get stuck and timeout

Tags: java, servlets, post, httpurlconnection

For some reason on the Serverside the content-length is 0 even though this Header was send and recieved.

By adding connection.setChunkedStreamingMode();
when sending a POST solved the issue, however I stil don't know why it's not working with the content-length Header.

Comment: Please ask a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) question. It is impossible to make any comment to your question.

Comment: Okay, I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wants to know why Setting "connection.setChunkedStreamingMode()"
did the trick.

The Client could send a request using http 1.0 or 1.1 but http 1.1 requests don't work with the content-length header added to it (which was added someware in the process). On the contrary the chunked mode does work for http 1.0 as well.

I tested this after I found this post from Clement Amarnath
[How do i send a POST request without Transfer Encoding:chunked from Jersey ReST Client 2.22.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217631/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-without-transfer-encodingchunked-from-jersey-rest)