# HttpURLConnection is not returning all headers

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm printing HTTP headers using the following code.

```
    URL url = new Url("htttp://example.com/example");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() +
                " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Here's the output :

```
Key : null ,Value : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Key : Accept-Ranges ,Value : [bytes]
Key : Cache-Control ,Value : [max-age=604800, public]
Key : Connection ,Value : [Keep-Alive]
Key : Date ,Value : [Mon, 03 Oct 2016 18:01:06 GMT]
Key : ETag ,Value : ["159eb4-53dce1f957880-gzip"]
Key : Expires ,Value : [Mon, 10 Oct 2016 18:01:06 GMT]
Key : Keep-Alive ,Value : [timeout=5, max=100]
Key : Last-Modified ,Value : [Sat, 01 Oct 2016 13:59:46 GMT]
Key : Server ,Value : [Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4]
Key : Transfer-Encoding ,Value : [chunked]
Key : Vary ,Value : [Accept-Encoding,User-Agent]
```

Now I'm trying via curl:

```
$ curl -v -D - http://example.com/example -o /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 111.111.111.111...
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0* Connected to example.com (111.111.111.111) port 80 (#0)
> GET example.com/example HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 03 Oct 2016 18:25:11 GMT
Date: Mon, 03 Oct 2016 18:25:11 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
< Last-Modified: Sat, 01 Oct 2016 13:59:46 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 01 Oct 2016 13:59:46 GMT
< ETag: "159eb4-53dce1f957880"
ETag: "159eb4-53dce1f957880"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 1416884
Content-Length: 1416884
< Cache-Control: max-age=604800, public
Cache-Control: max-age=604800, public
< Expires: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 18:25:11 GMT
Expires: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 18:25:11 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent

< 
{ [1080 bytes data]
 30 1383k   30  427k    0     0   116k      0  0:00:11  0:00:03  0:00:08  116k^C
```

See how the `Content-Length` header is missing in the java output? Why does this happen? How can I fix this?

Comment: It's provided via an API. There is no fix and you don't need one.

Comment: @EJP How come I don't need a fix? Shouldn't the API return `Content-Length` if the server sends a `Content-Length`?

Comment: The API I refer to is `getContentLength()` (and `getContentLengthLong()`).

Comment: I can reproduce your bug with `www.google.com`, the header is visible in curl but not with the Java code

Comment: @NicolasFilotto It isn't a bug yet. Can you show the header was sent in the Java case?

Comment: @EJP in my case it was because `curl` doesn't follow the redirect while the java code does by default so by calling `conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)` , I finally get the content length in the list of my headers

Comment: Try to call `conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)` to see if it helps

Comment: @EJP @NicolasFilotto `getContentLength()` returns -1 .

Comment: Have you added conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false) just after HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Yes. No change.

Answer (score 4):

`Content-Length` is missing because the server sent the response in chunks. It's the expected behavior. Look at the `Transfer-Encoding` header in the Java response, and here's [RFC 2616, 4.4 Message Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) (see the 3rd item of the list).

Comment: So how do I disable this?

Comment: @BinoyBabu i'm afraid that's not possible. See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174435/avoiding-chunked-encoding-of-http-1-1-response). [RFC 2616, 3.6.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.6.1) says `All HTTP/1.1 applications MUST be able to receive and decode the "chunked" transfer-coding`, so i think you'll have to cope with this header

Comment: @BinoyBabu [RFC 2616, 14.41](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.41) says `Many older HTTP/1.0 applications do not understand the Transfer-Encoding header`, so if you can configure the server and really wish to disable `Transfer-Encoding`, you can roll your server back to HTTP/1.0, but i strongly discourage it for you'll lose much of the 1.1 improvementes, such as `Transfer-Encoding` itself

Comment: Are you saying that it's impossible to find the content length from headers in HTTP 1.1? I have seen many programs doing this.

Comment: @BinoyBabu instead of observing the `Content-Length` header you'll have to find out the entity-body size by other means, e.g. downloading everything and counting the number of octets after that

Comment: @BinoyBabu to show download progress you'll have to do some server configuring to ensure that it doesn't split the response in chunks, so the response is sent as a whole with `Content-Length`. Or else it won't be possible to make the download progress

Comment: @BinoyBabu try to inspect the request headers wget and curl send to the server. Maybe there's a hint there

Answer (score 2):

The 'Content-Length' is parsed automatically and can be retrieved via `conn.getContentLength()` or `conn.getContentLengthLong()`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLengthLong() for more info.

Comment: I doesn't explain why the `content-length` is not in the headers, this will return `-1` if the header doesn't exist which is the case here

Comment: @NicolasFilotto It will return -1 if the header wasn't *sent*, which *isn't* the case here, according to the `curl` output.

Comment: @EJP no I have just tested with `www.google.com` with curl I see that `Content-Length` is 258 but with java this header is not part of the list so I get -1 when I call this method

Comment: @NicolasFilotto So it wasn't sent for some reason in the Java case.

Answer (score 0):

The response in case of java includes 'transfer-encoding' header which is missing in case of the curl response. Also when I tried it, I got a 404 (not found) for my attempt. I get a 404 when I try it from my browser as well.

My guess is that you have an overridden host entry for `example.com` that loops back to your own tomcat or similar. Its an issue with your environment.

This is what I get :

```
    /**
     *
     * <P> jdk-1.8 </P>
     * <PRE>
Key :null || Values :[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
Key :X-Cache || Values :[HIT]
Key :Server || Values :[ECS (ewr/1445)]
Key :Etag || Values :["359670651+gzip+ident"]
Key :Cache-Control || Values :[max-age=604800]
Key :x-ec-custom-error || Values :[1]
Key :Vary || Values :[Accept-Encoding]
Key :Last-Modified || Values :[Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT]
Key :Expires || Values :[Mon, 10 Oct 2016 19:20:29 GMT]
Key :Content-Length || Values :[1270]
Key :Date || Values :[Mon, 03 Oct 2016 19:20:29 GMT]
Key :Content-Type || Values :[text/html]
     * </PRE>
     * @param urlStr (http://example.com/example)
     */
    private static void printHeaders(String urlStr) {

        try {
            URL urlRef = new URL(urlStr);
            URLConnection urlConnection = urlRef.openConnection();
            Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();

            for (String headerName : headerFields.keySet()) {
                List<String> headerEntry = headerFields.get(headerName);
                System.out.println("Key :"+headerName +" || Values :"+headerEntry);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```