gRPC <-> REST Transcoding when streaming response in HTTP1.1
I'm working on an existing project that uses grpc-gateway to communicate between REST and gRPC services: https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/tutorials/introduction/
So I define my proto as follows, and the rest is magic (I still need to figure out what's going on within that project, but I assume that most of the code is generated):
SpaceGateway {
  rpc GetMoon(MoonRequest) returns (stream MoonResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v1/space"
      body: "*"
    };
  };
}

Now I can access my service via <url_prefix>/v1/space. Everything works fine, but I have concerns regarding the streaming response when the client supports only HTTP 1.1. When I sent a request using Postman/Curl, I saw that I start getting the response only when all chunks are received, i.e., it buffers responses internally. So my questions are as follows:
Who is performing the buffering and where?
Is it possible to configure transcoding so it won't buffer but will send chunks as soon as they arrive? According to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18174465/947111, HTTP 1.1 should support it.
Thank you in advance.
